# How to try out the new Ionic 4 (beta) with no side effect on the existing Ionic 3 apps (Win 10)?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Should I simply create a new project folder and run npm install ionic i.e. without the -g flag? So that this new Ionic v4 project will ONLY use the Ionic 4 stuffs?

My existing Ionic Info:
   ionic info

```
cli packages: 
(C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:
    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.11.2

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The `Ionic CLI` v4 has been released. In my experience, I think, it is now safe to upgrade it globally `npm install -g ionic` for both v3 and v4 apps

One the update CLI is installed globally, you could create a dummy app (choose `angular` project when doing `ionic start`) to try out Ionic v4

```
 npm install -g ionic
 cd somewhere_you_want_to_play
 ionic start my_ionic_v4_new_dummy_project
```

**UPDATE**

If you just want to check if the CLI v4 works with you existing app, you could for example install it somewhere and not globally (no `-g`) and always use the full path for the cmd, like

```
cd /somewhere_test_cli/
npm install ionic
cd /your_project/
/somewhere_test_cli/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic serve
```

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your reply.  I'm new to the Ionic and I had some Ionic 3 apps about to publish to the Google store.  That's why I posted this question so if I tried the v4 beta, it won't affect the existing apps.  From my previous experience, if I chose to upgrade the CLI which was prompted if I ran, for e.g., ionic cordova run android, my apps will return with many errors and I will need to downgrade the CLI.  So in your opinions, if we do use the recommended npm install -g ionic and if I run the existing Ionic 3 apps, there won't be any issues?  Thanks again...

Comment: @LHLK if you want you could give a try first. You could use tooling like `nvm` to helps you switch between nodes and libs. But you could also install the Ionic cli somewhere and just reference it to try

Comment: I added an example without nvm in my solution, just in case

Comment: David, just a quick update.  Your solution works out perfectly! It seems that the CLI 4.0.1 will not be installed if your Apps is developed under Ionic 3.  So I think it's safe to upgrade to CLI 4.0.1 to test out the Ionic v4 beta along with your existing Ionic 3 apps.  Hey thanks again...

Comment: By using David's method, I'd successfully installed the ionic 4 beta app with the following ionic 4 info:$ ionic info

Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.0.1 (E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.0
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.0-rc.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.0-rc.3
   @angular/cli               : 6.0.8
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.0
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.1
System:
   NodeJS : v8.11.2 (E:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10